# Dois Projetos GIT

Tags: java, git, github

Se eu tiver um projeto já sendo feito em `git` e em um dado momento eu precisar unir com outro projeto mas manter os históricos de `commit` tem como?

Comment: Sim, eu fiz isso para juntar três projetos distintos uma vez.

Comment: vc se lembra quais comandos?

Comment: eu achei esse aqui e to tentando, oq vc acha?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: O `subtree` tem um efeito distinto na minha lembrança... Eu não o usei; saí com merge tradicional mesmo, mas foi porque isso satisfazia melhor o meu caso

Comment: Pronto, você achou o link que eu tinha usado inicialmente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/4438007; quando fui testar, meu `git` não aceitou a flag `--allow-unrelated-histories`, então eu simplesmente a ignorei e deu certo. Faz tanto tempo que eu tinha até perdido esse link

Comment: Eu posso estar enganado, mas creio que o .gitignore possa ajudar a evitar de fazer update em coisas dos repositiorios distintos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, só não sei como fazer `.gitignore` para remotos específicos (se foi isso que você quis dizer)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado você tem razão não iria funcionar, não tenho certeza mas acho que talvez isto funcione https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906964/1518921

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso é novidade para mim, nunca fui de mexer dentro do pasta `.git` xD

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu também não, por isto nem chutei respostas, acho que por linha de comando é bem mais prático, mas vamos vendo com o tempo, se tiver uma oportunidade irei testar e deixar como resposta alternativa

Answer (score 3):

> Isso foi uma necessidade no trabalho, tinha de juntar alguns repositórios. Adaptei o que está [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/4438007), para conseguir sanar o meu problema. Agradecimentos ao AP por descobrir o link original que eu havia perdido

Saiba que você vai precisar de muita disciplina para isso.

Vou falar da minha experiência juntando 3 repositórios em um novo, ok?

Primeiro passo, foi criar o novo repositório para agregar os outros. Iniciei esse repositório com um commit inicial (de `README.md` mesmo) para ter um ponto de partida. Criei um novo branch chamado `raiz` com esse commit (não altero ele, entretanto).

Então, adicionei os repositórios remotos desejados:

```
git remote add repo_old1 https://url/to/repo1
git remote add repo_old2 https://url/to/repo2
```

Então, fiz o seguinte:

```
git checkout raiz -b master
git merge repo_old1/master
mkdir repo1_dir
git mv {arquivos do repo1} repo1_dir/
git commit -m 'Sandboxando o repo1'

git merge repo_old2/master
mkdir repo2_dir
git mv {arquivos do repo2} repo2_dir/
git commit -m 'Sandboxando o repo2'
```

Em seguida, precisa fazer o mesmo para o develop; no caso, comecei indo para o branch `raiz` e fazendo a mesma operação:

```
git checkout raiz -b develop
git merge repo_old1/develop
mkdir repo1_dir
git mv {arquivos do repo1} repo1_dir/
git commit -m 'Sandboxando o repo1'

git merge repo_old2/develop
mkdir repo2_dir
git mv {arquivos do repo2} repo2_dir/
git commit -m 'Sandboxando o repo2'
```

Então, só faltou dar o `push`:

```
git checkout master && git push -u origin master
git checkout develop && git push -u origin develop
```

---

O passo de isolar os repositórios em pastas distintas foi estratégia minha, pois o foco dos repositórios inicias eram distintos. Um era TotalCross, outro GWT, e o terceiro era a dependência comum entre os dois.